# Yii2: Js to add form field

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a button "click" that show form when someone click it and if click again then it show more form fields. I used this code but it's not working, nothing is showed. Please help me with this. I am not so good at JS. And sorry for my bad English.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<div class="parent">

</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<input id="btnSubmit" class="mail" type="submit" value="Click"/>
<script  type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $('.parent').append(" <?= $form->field($model, 'result[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?> 

<?= $form->field($model, 'score[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?> ");
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful for you: https://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/create

Comment: thank you :) But i really want to archive this without using extension